# Sitecore.XA.Feature.Composites.EventHandlers.SaveCompositeItems.GetNewLayoutFromRequest throws exception when importing

Tags: sxa, creative-exchange

We have exported our site and then without change anything we tried to upload it back and got the error below. The item id it refers is a Silde Datasource Item from a Carousel Composite and there is another errors for Accordion Datasoure Items too. Without this items in page the import succeeds. Do you have experienced this problem already? Anyone can help us?

---

```
<exception>
ManagedPoolThread #17 10:03:57 ERROR Failed to save the item. Item ID: {24F98447-85FF-404F-8932-D9C9B9C374D1}, database: master
ManagedPoolThread #17 10:03:57 ERROR An error occured while importing a rendering in file: index.html
System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saving' event. 
---> System.NullReferenceException: Reference not set to instance of an object.
   em Sitecore.XA.Feature.Composites.EventHandlers.SaveCompositeItems.GetNewLayoutFromRequest(String newlayout)
   em Sitecore.XA.Feature.Composites.EventHandlers.SaveCompositeItems.PropagateLayoutChanges(Item item)
   em Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
   --- End of stacktrace ---
   em Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
   em Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
   em Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaving(Object sender, ItemSavingEventArgs args)
   em Sitecore.Events.Event.DataEngine_ItemSaving(Object sender, ExecutingEventArgs`1 e)
   em System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   em Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)
   em Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseExecuting(Boolean& cancelled)
   em Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.CanExecute()
   em Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   em Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item)
   em Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.SaveItem.TriggerDataEngine.Process(SaveItemArgs args)
   em (Object , Object )
   em Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   em Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.SaveItem(Item item)
   em Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent)
   em Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.EndEdit(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent)
   em Sitecore.Data.Items.EditContext.Dispose()
   em Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Pipelines.Import.RenderingProcessing.GridStylesImporter.UpdateGridParameters(ImportRenderingProcessingArgs args, IEnumerable`1 gridClasses)
   em (Object , Object )
   em Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   em Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   em Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   em Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Pipelines.Import.PageProcessing.RenderingParser.Process(ImportPageProcessingArgs args)
```

---

This is the html that's being imported for that item ID mentioned in stacktrace:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="component content col-12 custom-css" data-pageid="{24F98447-85FF-404F-8932-D9C9B9C374D1}" data-renderingid="{8B0393E9-EE25-4F0B-A5FD-777B3AD2C737}" data-uniqueid="{AA33EC4B-4ED1-4EEE-B791-63044DC4430D}" data-variantid="{7C5FEDFB-F002-4136-99B0-5ED23040938B}" data-stylesfield="Styles" data-gridfield="GridParameters" data-renderingclass="content">
    <div class="component-content">
        <div class="field-slideimage"><img src="-/media/Project/Tenant/Site/Header_Container.jpg" alt="Slide" width="2049" height="990" data-variantitemid="{24F98447-85FF-404F-8932-D9C9B9C374D1}" customdata="ew0KICAiJHR5cGUiOiAiU3lzdGVtLkNvbGxlY3Rpb25zLkdlbmVyaWMuS2V5VmFsdWVQYWlyYDJbW1N5c3RlbS5TdHJpbmcsIG1zY29ybGliXSxbU3lzdGVtLk9iamVjdCwgbXNjb3JsaWJdXVtdLCBtc2NvcmxpYiIsDQogICIkdmFsdWVzIjogWw0KICAgIHsNCiAgICAgICJLZXkiOiAiSXNJbkN1cnJlbnRJdGVtUmVuZGVyaW5ncyIsDQogICAgICAiVmFsdWUiOiBmYWxzZQ0KICAgIH0NCiAgXQ0KfQ==" data-variantfieldname="SlideImage"></div>
        <div class="slide-info">
            <div class="field-slidetext">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p>
                    Subtitle
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="field-slidelink"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```